# In okHttp, SNI is not seen in IP based uri whereas SNI is coming for FQDN based uri

Tags: java, okhttp, tls1.2

By default, `okHttp` supports SNI, but for IP based uri we are not able to see SNI in pcap and its not working.

Need help in resolving it.

Comment: SNI is required to be a DNS name, and an address is not a DNS name. Java correctly does not send an address as SNI. An IP-based server doesn't need SNI because it already knows, _before_ the SSL/TLS handshake, what address you connected to.

Comment: This should be an answer ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNI is strictly for DNS hostnames.  It doesn't exist as a possibility for IP addresses.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3546#section-3.1

> "HostName" contains the fully qualified DNS hostname of the server,
> as understood by the client. The hostname is represented as a byte
> string using UTF-8 encoding [UTF8], without a trailing dot.